# Why integer result minus 1

Tags: integer

i have something to ask about the maximum of integers and vice versa

[image: like in the picture]

why is max integer reduced by 1
yes 31, because the positives and negatives are subtracted (this is not what I mean)

I mean the result is minus 1

(2^31) - 1 = 2,147,483,647
([image: picture])

and why if the minimum integer, is not reduced by 1

2^31 = 2,147,483,647
([image: picture])

Answer (score 1):

> why is max integer reduced by 1

Because there is one integer which is neither negative nor positive, yet must be represented somehow: `0`.

> and why if the minimum integer, is not reduced by 1

This is just a convention. You could do it the other way around: represent all numbers from -2<sup>31</sup>…(+2<sup>31</sup>-1). Either way works. The conventional way has some mathematical and representational advantages, so it is not entirely arbitrary.